# Expected value of three consecutive cards of same value?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, random-variables

If you had a deck of 52 cards, shuffled it, and then fanned it out, what would be the expected number of triples? The probability would be $E[I]=(\frac {3}{51})*(\frac {2}{50})$. But what would you multiply that by to get $E[X]$? I know for adjacent pairs it is $51*(\frac {3}{51})$. But I don't believe the same applies for triples.

Answer (score 1):

The same does apply for triples.  The chance that a card starts a triple is $\frac 6{51\cdot 50}$ as you say.  There are $50$ cards that can start triples, so the expected number is $\frac 6{51}$

Answer (score 1):

There's $50$ places where a triple can occur, and you correctly noticed that the expectation at any one of these is $(3 \cdot 2)/(51 \cdot 50)$. By the [linearity of expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/), you only need to sum these up for all $50$ places. So, its $6/51 = 2/17$ expected in total.